# Can you change an iPhone startup screen background from white to black?

Tags: iphone, startup, screen

It seems light-coloured iPhones have a white startup background colour with black Apple logo. As you can’t control the brightness on startup - this screen is offensively bright at night - searing your darkness-adjusted eyes and waking any nearby creature who happens to be peacefully sleeping.

Can you invert it like on dark-coloured iPhones? Black background, white Apple logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you jailbreak the phone, no...can't be done.

The startup screen even ignores the accessibility settings.

Comment: I agree that it can be annoyingly bright. The startup screen is displayed during the boot sector code. iOS isn’t even up and running yet, and the boot sector is locked at the factory, so even a jailbreak wouldn’t help. At best it would be full white until iOS booted. Also, the boot sector can’t be unlocked. It’s like blowing a fuse.

Comment: Please file a RADAR. Maybe they’ll fix it in future hardware versions.

Comment: done - https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=50686210

Comment: Thank you. I've whined about this problem often, but thought I was the only one who found it painful to have a flashlight shining at me during startup. Here's hoping that Apple makes the startup screen more subtle.

Comment: Just received this from Apple: Hi Jayden,

As a result of your feedback, there are software changes in build iOS 13 beta 1 (17A5492t) that have resolved this issue.

Has this issue been fixed for you?

Feedback ID 6100733, Insanely bright white screen on bootup 50686210 

Do not reply to this email.  Please login to Feedback Assistant and let us know if the problem is fixed for you.

Comment: Wow, Apple is being very responsive these days. Thanks for taking the initiative to file a RADAR. Once we get to beta 2, I'll download it and see how it works!  BTW, unless you're a serious thrill seeker NEVER get an Apple beta 1...50% success rate of hard bricking your device

Comment: Yeah I agree about Apple being responsive! Perhaps because it was just a glaringly obvious (pun intended) problem - they prioritised it.  haha I did try a beta once, and there were bugs everywere. I don't think it was beta 1 though. Even still - probably won't do it again unless I'm working on an app! Thanks for the tip!